# Handling large Input data in a Java Application

Tags: java, import-from-excel

I have a web application in which I need to input large amount of data from an Excel formatted file - say 10,000 rows and 200 columns. I then need to process this data and then insert / update / delete from a database.

I have tried doing this by putting everything in the java code app but it turns out to be too slow.

Could anyone suggest a better way to this? Note I am not putting this data into some classes or objects. I am just processing and updating the db.

Comment: Your question seems a bit vague, and looks a bit more like a work dump then anything else. It would help if you showed _what_ you have, otherwise it is _very_ hard to answer your question. _Why_ is it too slow. _What_ is in the file?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use a streaming technique. Use Apache Commons FileUpload:
http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/streaming.html

and then process records one by one, this way you will not be allocating memory. Things to consider: what happens if your process breaks in the middle? Use transactions if this is important for you. Unfortunately I can't give you tips on reading XLS format, but if you can do CSV, things will be simpler - there are few libs for that.

You can fine-tune FileUpload to store data in memory, disk or a combination.. or you can trust it to do the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear what is going on in your application: are you interacting with user input (upload) or you are just initializing the application? If it's the later, data update could certainly be done once when mounting the application instead of on the request phase. If it's the former, it depends on many factors: how do you read the data? File IO could be very slow; how do you update the database? - Use a stored procedure? or just plain JDBC SQL clause. Maybe some kind of a background thread would be better if it seems too slow for the whole process to finish.